# set value of property for mock in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write some unit tests for an angular service which allows publishing changes to a list. This class instantiates another factory which holds the list and does much of the api requests. To test some of the code, I simply need to set the value of `Factory.pk` in the with fake data, but I can't figure out how to do it. I don't necessarily need to spy on it, just set its value. 
Code kind of looks like:

```
// constructor of service
function publishService (ListFactory) {
    var _PublishFactory = new ListFactory(),
        item_pk: _PublishFactory.item_pk,
        setItemPk: setItemPk
};

// . . . code I'm trying to test:
function setItemPk(pk) {
    // this SHOULD set _PublishFactory.item_pk;
    return _PublishFactory.setItemPk(pk);
}

function addItem(item) {
    item_pk = _PublishFactory.pk;
    // do things with the list/and whatever here
}

// test:
describe('test', function () {
var publish,
    mock;

beforeEach(module('app'));
beforeEach(function() {
    inject(function(publish) {
         publishService = publish;
    });
    inject(function($injector) {
         mock = $injector.get('ListFactory');
    });

it('should addItem', function() {
    spyOn(mock.prototype, 'setItemPk').and.returnValues(0, 1);
    publishService.setItemPk(0);
    publishService.setItemPk(1);
    publishService.addItems(data[0]);
    publishService.addItems(data[1]);
});


});

});
```

The problem I have is that when I get to `publishService.addItem` in the test, `_PublishFactory.item_pk` is `undefined`, even though it gets set correctly in the `publishService.setItemPk`. If I put some loglines in there it looks like this should work.

I'm trying to figure out if I can just `mock` the _PublishFactory.pk value at the top of each `addItem` call, but it's a property, not a function. I don't need to spy on it, I just need to set it. When I try to set it, I get a read-only error from Jasmine.

thx

Comment: You're replacing the setItemPK in your factory with this code `spyOn(mock.prototype, 'setItemPk').and.returnValues(0, 1);`. Therefore, the code in the original never runs.

Comment: okay, so to clarify, I can mock a function, and I can set a property with a function. I was trying to do both at once here and they were canceling each other out? I removed the `spyOn` line and the test passes.

Comment: Use `and.callThrough()` if you want the actual code to run.

Comment: Note that you probably want to spy on the instance, not the prototype.

Comment: awesome, thanks everyone.